# SQL Windowing accumulative sum with grouping

Tags: sql, aggregate, presto, windowing

I've got a table like this

```
|week_no|value|attribute|
-------------------------
|   1   |  3  |    a    |
|   2   |  3  |    a    |
|   3   |  3  |    a    |
|   1   |  4  |    b    |
|   2   |  4  |    b    |
|   3   |  4  |    b    |
```

I'd like to have an accumulative account of the value column

```
|week_no|value|attribute|accum_value|
-------------------------------------
|   1   |  3  |    a    |     3     |
|   2   |  3  |    a    |     6     |
|   3   |  3  |    a    |     9     |
|   1   |  4  |    b    |     4     |
|   2   |  4  |    b    |     8     |
|   3   |  4  |    b    |    12     |
```

I've attempted doing the above by using this windowing function though it doesn't seem to be returning the correct values

```
SUM(value) OVER(ORDER BY 1 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS accum_value
```

Comment: MySQL does not support window functions, so I assume you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct window function would use `partition by`:

```
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY attribute ORDER BY week_no
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                ) AS accum_value
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, if anything I've gotten the same results as looking at the raw attributes but with some form of multiplier on them.